# Why are there so few Notes / Domino questions on SO?

Tags: discussion, not-constructive

Is the number of IBM Lotus Notes / Domino questions on SO indicative of the size of the developer community, quality of the community, or something else?

I realize this is probably argumentative, but compared to other platforms, Domino is WAY underrepresented on SO. So, is it because there are just that few active Notes/Domino devs these days (not what I'd guess based on the activity of the forums on IBM.com), or do they ignore the site because they think it's a .Net site (which it clearly isn't - there are a LOT of other platforms that get much love on SO), or is the community as a whole just missing a great opportunity?

Comment: People still use Lotus Notes?

Comment: @Nicholas: oh  *yeah!* you would be surprised *who* uses it these days...

Comment: It's because the products are so solid, they hardly need manuals, much less support! Why ask questions on SO, when it works right, straight out of the box?     (IBM, please send my check to [redacted].)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SO is generally a mirror of what is in demand for programmers. In its early stages, SO was extremely Microsoft centric, mostly due to Jeff / Joel / Jon working mostly with C# / .NET.

I think it has since leveled quite a bit, and provides a reasonably good mirror of current programming trends, languages and problems.

Don't mistake a general lack of questions regarding Notes / Domino as an indication that they could not be answered on SO, but as an indication that not many SO users are currently working with either. People who have worked with either are still just as capable of answering questions about them.

It isn't like Pascal, for instance which is still used as a teaching language, hence keeping its popularity alive.

Comment: I think this best reflects my opinion. There are plenty of qualified Notes/Domino devs out there, but they aren't SO users. Although, I am starting to think they would be better off if they used SO.

Answer (score -2):

I have heard of Notes but not Domino. Maybe because it's not free and open-source. There are a lot of replacement apps in the collaboration software field which are free or open-source.

Comment: I would agree except that the whole .Net platform isn't exactly free or open source either.